# Errors trying to conda install packages that are dependent on gdal (rasterio , geopandas, etc.)

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal, geopandas, rasterio

When I try to pip install rasterio I get this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdaab8u77'
       cwd: C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fbbbi7de\rasterio
  Complete output (2 lines):
  INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
  ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
```

---

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 
'C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' 
get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jones\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdaab8u77' 
Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have no idea what is happening. I installed `gdal` using the wheel. I have `GDAL_DATA` and `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` environment variables, I dont know where a GDAL-config file is to add.

When i try to import `GDAL` into `conda`, I get:
`ImportError: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.`

When I try to `conda install` `rasterio` or `gdal` it fails the initial solve and then hangs in solving the environment for a while.

I am running `windows 10`, `python 3.7`, `conda 4.8.3`.

Comment: Since you mention conda, you should try to install those packages using `conda install`, and not `pip install` (rasterio doesn't provide binaries to install with pip on windows, so that is the reason it tries to build from source). You say that with cnda, the solve fails. Can you be more specific? Eg show the command you ran and the error you got?

Comment: @joris this is what I ran.  >conda install rasterio
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort

Comment: @joris 
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:  
It then printed lots of errors like this:
Package pyrsistent conflicts for:
anaconda==2020.02 -> pyrsistent==0.15.7[build='py38he774522_0|py36he774522_0|py37he774522_0']
nbformat -> jsonschema[version='>=2.4,!=2.5.0'] -> pyrsistent[version='>=0.14.0']
jupyterlab_server -> jsonschema[version='>=3.0.1'] -> pyrsistent[version='>=0.14.0']
anaconda==2020.02 -> jsonschema==3.2.0=py36_0 -> pyrsistent[version='>=0.14.0']

Comment: @jorit. This is also in the output, before printing the conflicts. 
Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Comment: You can edit your question to include additional information (as comment it is hard to read the output). Also, I would advise to create an new environment https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#creating-a-new-environment

Comment: @joris i was able to successfully install in a new environment. I am not too familiar with how this works going forward and writing programs. Can I still use this library with libraries installed in the root environment?